# Visual Studio Cordova iframe error

Tags: cordova, iframe

I use Visual Studio 2015 Cordova.
I got an iframe error, 
it works well on ripple emulator, but when i debugged on the device, the iframe didn't work.

config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
```

index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: http://www.wikipedia.org http://fonts.googleapis.com https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

index.html iframe

```
<iframe src='http://www.wikipedia.org' style='width:100%; height:100%; overflow-y: hidden;' scrolling='no' seamless='seamless'>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There is consistency issue with **iframe** in device browser..
i suggest use InAppBrowser instead of iframe in cordova..
Check this [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html)... 
Hope this help you.

Comment: can i use it like iframe (inside a div) ? 
thank you

Comment: I think you can't because this is plug-in and you have to call separately.

Answer (score 0):

If Savan's answer doesn't work try the [whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

Comment: it worked on emulator, but on device i got an error :
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS . thank you